# Is it possible to reduce the optimization from high dimension to one dimension?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am now doing an optimization problem. Currently, I have codes in optimization `min f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)`. It may give `x_1,x_2,...,x_n` to be different in values after optimization. However, suppose I want to make that `x_1=x_2=...=x_n` and do the optimization again, what I expect is to find `y` such that `f(y,y,...,y)` is minimized. Setting `x_1,x_2,...,x_n` to be all the same as the initial input, but still, it may produce different values of `x_1,x_2,...,x_n`. Are there any good ways to solve the problem without rewriting the codes? Any existing functions/techniques can help me to do it? If possible, you can treat the function is not known (the codes of functions is not accessible, what I know is that for the function, when input `n` parameters, it gives a value).

Comment: You would have to specify that as constraints. I.e. `n-1` simple pairwise linear equality constraints.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to add the optimization bound that all parameters are the same?

Comment: Yes, I call them decision variables (parameters have a different meaning in different contexts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Erwin Kalvelagen, the most general approach is to define it as equality constraints, but if it is your goal to simplify your problem, you can define a new function which accepts a single input value and forwards it to every input of your function `f`. Assuming you are using `fmincon`, the solution is:

```
x = fmincon(@(x) f(x, x, x, ..., x), x0, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand how to do it now.

Comment: @will_cheuk Please mark answers as correct if they solved your problem. This will help other people with the same question to find a correct answer and will save us some time by not looking in a question that is already answered correctly.

Comment: Gradients are an interesting exercise.